# JAXB to map XML element to DTO

Tags: jaxb

Can we map XML like

```
<root>
  <tagA>
    <prop>111</prop>
    <prop>222</prop>
    <prop>333</prop>
    <prop>444</prop>
  </tagA>
  <tagB>
    <prop>555</prop>
    <prop>666</prop>
  </tagB>
  <tagC>
    <prop>777</prop>
  </tagC>
</root>
```

to

```
class MyDto {
  private List<TagA> tagAProps;
  private List<TagB> tagBProps;
  private List<TagC> tagCProps;
}
```

using JAXB? I am not sure how to use annotation to directly map elements to collection type. Straight mapping into POJO has five different classes (Root, TagA, TagB, TagC and Prop). Of which TagA, TagB and TagC being all similar. So I want to have this minimum number of class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the `@XmlElementWrapper` and `@XmlElement` annotations for this:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class MyDto {
  @XmlElementWrapper(name="tagA")
  @XmlElement(name="prop")
  private List<String> tagAProps;

  @XmlElementWrapper(name="tagB")
  @XmlElement(name="prop")
  private List<String> tagBProps;

  @XmlElementWrapper(name="tagC")
  @XmlElement(name="prop")
  private List<String> tagCProps;
}
```

Comment: I think my DTO should have three List<String> instead of List<TagX> to represent my XML correctly and @Blaise Doughan solution should work.

Comment: @anjibman - That's correct, I've now changed the answer to have `List<String>` instead of `List<TagX>`.